# how to refresh one view from another view using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I have two different views(not a parent view),I want to refresh/reload one page from another page,how to do this using javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with javascript because those are 2 separate views that are never rendered in the same HTML page at the same time. Don't forget that javascript works on the client. This could be done with partial views that are rendered within some main view. You could use for example AJAX to refresh those partial views. With standard views you use standard HTML techniques - things like HTML forms or anchor links to navigate between your controller actions (that in terms will be rendering different views).

Comment: can i use window.location.href=url or any other methods

Comment: Yeah, sure, you could use `window.location.href = url` to redirect to another controller action using javascript if you wish.

Comment: I used the above one but the page is refreshing but that page(refreshing) is displaying on the same page

Comment: And where did you expect it to display? The `window.location.href` method navigates away from the current url to the target url that you specified. What exactly did you expect to happen other than that?

Comment: my main view is displaying in the left side of my view page,and another view is there in the right side of my view page,when i select an item in right view,the leftside view has to refresh

Comment: You cannot have 2 views at the same time. I think you are confusing the notions here. You can only have 1 main view which consists of multiple **partial views**. As I have already stated in my answer you could use AJAX to update those partial views while staying on the main page and without navigating away. If this is the case I invite you to read more about AJAX. Things like the `Ajax.*` MVC helpers and jQuery might be helpful in your scenario.